# Transitivity of "to map" in mathematical nomenclature

Tags: transitivity

Is "to map" a transitive verb, so that I can say "a mapping b" (a related with b), or an intransitive verb, so that I can say "a mapping with b" or "a is mapped with b" or "a mapping to b"?

Answer (score 3):

It's a transitive verb. But it can be used in more than one form:

> He's **mapping** the island.
>
> She is **mapping out** a plan for the meeting.
>
> If more than one suffix can be **mapped on** to the end of a word then the longest is chosen for removal [(reference)](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/map?q=to%20map)

*A mapping with B* can be used but B is not an object in the sentence.

> He's **mapping with** a *piece of chalk* the whole island.